# Is there any difference between top-level modules and local modules?

Tags: module, f#

I am a newbe to F#, but am quite familiar with C#. And I was wondering if there is a difference between declaring top level modules and local modules (e.g. performance, etc.), other than that the namespace declaration is not needed for top-level modules (it is part of the module declaration).
I cannot find anything in the documentation ([MSDN F# Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233221.aspx)) specifying other differences.

Basically, coming from the C# world I prefer

```
//Version 1
namespace My.Namespace

module MyModule = 
    let a = 1
```

over

```
//Version 2
module My.Namespace.MyModule
let a = 1
```

Given that in both versions there will be only one module in the file, does Version 2 bring any disadvantages (compared to Version 1)?

Comment: You only need the first version when you have multiple modules in the same file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are equivalent. According to F# 3.0 [specs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819001):

> An implementation file that begins with a module declaration defines a
>   single namespace declaration group with one module. For example:
>
> ```
> module MyCompany.MyLibrary.MyModule
>     let x = 1
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> namespace MyCompany.MyLibrary
> module MyModule = 
>      let x = 1
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer I was looking for!